# Actual coordinate after ScaleTransfrom()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scaletransform

I am drawing a rectangle in a WinForms application in C# and I want to get the actual coordinates of the rectangle after applying `ScaleTransform()` method.

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.ScaleTransform(2.0F,2.0F,System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append);
g.DrawRectangle(pen, 20, 40, 100,100)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have set a `ScaleTransform` in your `Graphics` object (or any transform for that matter), you can use it to transform the points of your rectangle (or any other points).

For example:

```
// your existing code
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.ScaleTransform(2.0F,2.0F,System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append);

// say we have some rectangle ...
Rectangle rcRect = new Rectangle(20, 40, 100, 100);

// make an array of points
Point[] pPoints =
{
    new Point(rcRect.Left, rcRect.Top),      // top left
    new Point(rcRect.Right, rcRect.Top),     // top right
    new Point(rcRect.Left, rcRect.Bottom),   // bottom left
    new Point(rcRect.Right, rcRect.Bottom),  // bottom right
};

// get a copy of the transformation matrix
using (Matrix mat = g.Transform)
{
    // use it to transform the points
    mat.TransformPoints(pPoints);
}
```

Note the `using` syntax above - this is because, as MSDN says:

> Because the matrix returned and by the Transform property is a copy of
>   the geometric transform, you should dispose of the matrix when you no
>   longer need it.

As a slightly less wordy alternative, you can do the same thing using the `TransformPoints` method of the `Graphics` class ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fsfk76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) - so construct your array of points as above, then just do this:

```
g.TransformPoints(CoordinateSpace.Page, CoordinateSpace.World, pPoints);
```

MSDN describes the relevant coordinate spaces used in the above function:

> GDI+ uses three coordinate spaces: world, page, and device. World
>   coordinates are the coordinates used to model a particular graphic
>   world and are the coordinates you pass to methods in the .NET
>   Framework. Page coordinates refer to the coordinate system used by a
>   drawing surface, such as a form or a control. Device coordinates are
>   the coordinates used by the physical device being drawn on, such as a
>   screen or a printer. The Transform property represents the world
>   transformation, which maps world coordinates to page coordinates.

Comment: Thank you so much,Roger.You help me a lot and now it works!I wish that I have enough reputation to vote your answer. :)